# Ruby on Rails 4 Whenever cron job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I would like to use Whenever gem to run scheduled jobs in my RoR application. I run the bundle install and this is my schedule.rb:

```
every 1.minute do
   runner "Event.executeEvents"
end
```

My Event.executeEvents method is a simple log entry:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def executeEvents
    puts "executeEvents at [" + Time.now.inspect + "]"
  end
end
```

If I execute `whenever` in command line, I got this:

```
$ whenever                       
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd C:/dev/yanpyapi && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Event.executeEvents'\'''

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

Nothing is executed.

What I´m missing?

Do I need to initilize it somehow? 
I have read some doc about capistrano and RVM, but I don´t know what is this for...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548730/cron-job-not-working-in-whenever-gem/13257752#13257752

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to execute

```
whenever -i
```

to add the jobs to crontab

Comment: I get this error when I do it: $ whenever -i
[fail] Couldn't write crontab; try running `whenever' with no options to ensure your schedule file is valid.

Comment: Add note: I´m trying to run it in a Windows 7. Does it work? I think it will only work on Unix systems...

Answer (score 2):

Also, #executeEvents is defined as an instance method.

In the schedule.rb file you are calling it as class method.