# How to test rake tasks with Whenever Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I'm trying to execute a simple rake task using whenever gem but the code isn't being executed.

I already set the environment to development, I updated the cron using the whenever --update-crontab command and the rake task works well if I run the command on console. But, when I run the server the log file is not being generated.

I saw a question here too with the same problem but it was solved setting the environment to development, but didn't work out for me.

My rake task:

```
namespace :testando do
  task :consulta => :environment do
    produto = Produto.first
    puts produto.nm_produto
  end  
end
```

My schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron_log.log"
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.minute do
  rake "testando:consulta"
end
```

I'm using rails 5.0.0.1 and I'm programing in Cloud9, so I think the OS is Ubuntu.

What's missing ?

Update:

I followed the instructions of the main answer in this topic [Cron job not working in Whenever gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548730/cron-job-not-working-in-whenever-gem)

And it worked! The task is running even with the server not being started (with "rails s" command).

Comment: you can find step by step implementation on whenever gem 
 at https://www.sitepoint.com/schedule-cron-jobs-whenever-gem/

Comment: I did all the instructions. Still doesn't work. Could the problem be with the path of my output file ?

Answer (score 0):

please run crontab -l to see if you have updated the crontab successfully

Comment: # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/ubuntu/workspace/site_paraiso/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/site_paraiso && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake testando:consulta --silent >> /home/ubuntu/workspace/site_paraiso/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/ubuntu/workspace/site_paraiso/config/schedule.rb